# iOS 17 widget missing images

Tags: ios17, ioswidgets

Hi I trying out our widget on iOS 17 but unfortunately the icon images in the widget are not showing and in XCode it's displaying these errors:

> -[INIntent _initWithIdentifier:backingStore:schema:error:] Missing backing store for Intent:  (N/A - N/A)
> -[INIntent _initWithIdentifier:backingStore:schema:error:] Missing backing store for Intent:  (N/A - N/A)
> The body of the Widget entries' view contains the following unsupported types: _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView, _CALayerView<CAL

Here is the code

```
HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top) {
            Spacer()

            Link(destination: URL(string: "xxx:123")!) {
              VStack {
                Button {
                } label: {
                  Image("Btn1")
                }
                Text("btn1").font(.system(size: 11, weight: .regular)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
              }
            }
          
            Spacer()

            Link(destination: URL(string: "xxx:456")!) {
              
              VStack {
                Button {
                } label: {
                  Image("btn2")

                }
                Text("btn2").font(.system(size: 11, weight: .regular)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
              }
            }
```

and the code Was working fine in previous iOS versions (devices and simulators)

Weird found out one of the header images (without button) above the buttons are working though:

```
HStack{
    Image("header1")
    Text("header1").font(.system(size: 13.5, weight: .semibold))
}.padding(.leading, 28)
```

Is it caused by the type of images provided?